# preg_match error in for-loop with phpexcel

Tags: symfony, preg-match, phpexcel

In my Symfony2 project, I am currently using the following for-loop:

```
        $blockCells = $worksheet->rangeToArray($firstRow.':'.$lastRow);
        foreach ($blockCells as $cell) {

            $newContent = $cell[0];

            // 2. RETRIEVE FOLDER ID
            $re = '/^[^_]+(?=_)/';
            preg_match($re,$cell[0], $_myid);
            $output->writeln('ID: '.$_myid[0]);

            $activesheet->setCellValue('F'.$counter, $_myid);

            $counter +=1;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]            
Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

Only when hiding **setCellValue**, the for-loop seems to be running well. Therefor it seems that PHPExcel is colliding with PHP's preg_match.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening and how I can solve this?

**UPDATE** (simplified the code)

the code above, gives the following output in the console:

```
ID: 10
```

After which it will throw the error. In other words, the for-loop runs once, then at the end, almost magically, it runs over the for-loop once more without actually executing it, and stops because of the error.

Comment: Check to make sure that the `$_content` variable in `preg_match($re,$_content, $_myid);` and  `preg_match($re, $_content, $my_match);` is not an array.  PHP is thinking that it is and that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: like Quixrick said, you surely give an array at line 8.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out all of step 8 and then uncommenting them one by one to see which is causing the issue?

Comment: @Quixrick: yes I understood that. $_content is certainly not an array. somewhere phpexcel is interfering...

Comment: @qooplmao. Good point. Turns out, commenting only this line out:                 $activesheet->setCellValue('F'.$counter, $_myid); is letting the script run just fine

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Turns out the mistake is in this line:

```
$activesheet->setCellValue('F'.$counter, $_myid);
```

which should be:

```
$activesheet->setCellValue('F'.$counter, $_myid[0]);
```

$_myid (instead of $_myid[0]) was passed on to the preg_match and is indeed an array.